# how can I abort previous axios call or how to do autocomplete perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am trying to build an application where user can search for various items. now my question is how can I send efficiently user search request to the server ?

example , user will type something (say 15 characters). For every 1 character he is sending one request to the server (using axios). now he is typing so fast, within 3 seconds he has sent 15 request to the server.. due to 15 parallel requests, my app is showing the actual result lately (or sometime failing). please help me how can i solve it.. I am using react native with axios.

example:

```
async searchLocation(text) {
    
    if (text.length > 3) {
      this.setState({searching: true, searchResultWindow: true});
      var getSearchResult = await searchPlace(text); /// Here I am making axios call to our server
      this.setState({searching: false, searchResults: getSearchResult.message});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried debounce https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce. Set the state for every keystrokes(immediately) but debounce api call and call after some delay

Comment: @ArfatBinkileb thank you so much.. this is what i wanted

Comment: Great. Happy that it helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to handle that case

```
let timer //the global variable to track the timer
async searchLocation(text) {
    
    if (text.length > 3) {
      //remove the API trigger within 3 seconds
      clearTimeout(timer)
      //assign new timer for the API call
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({searching: true, searchResultWindow: true});
        var getSearchResult = await searchPlace(text); /// Here I am making axios call to our server
        this.setState({searching: false, searchResults: getSearchResult.message});
     }, 3000) //the API only triggers once users stop typing after 3 seconds
    }
  }
```

If you want to have deeper understanding, you can read this article

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can divide the issue into two steps

- At the first you must find a word that the user wants to type for search (**not result of search**)
  in this step, you can just use a dictionary
- The second step is finding user search results after pressing **Enter key** or Click to the search button